# Facing issue with gradle. Also Android Studio is blacking out the Build bundle/apk

Tags: gradle, flutter, publishing

After creating my first app, I thought to upload the app to Play Store. However, when I prepared files for upload, because I am using Flutter, I added all the requirements to the files. However, when I checked the build.gradle in the android directory, it shows the Can't Resolve symbols for Properties, GradleException, and FileInputStream.

[Image for Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8j4K.png)

Also, when I am trying to build apk via Build>Build bundle/APK, I found out that is been greyed out.

[Image for Build Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGowr.png)

After creating app before I saw this problem, I had the problem with uploading the app. Whenever uploading it responds with the error that it has been signed when in debug. However, I signed it using the key generated by Keytool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

Gradle isn't implemented for flutter yet. Let the errors be shown. Else using VS Code will help

Comment: You told the what, but how did you fix this issue?